# page breaks and css - how to skip last page?

Tags: html, css, page-break

**I have an issue with page-breaks and css**:

I have this html-code (which is generated by php)

```
<div class="form-table courses">
coursename and pupils...
</div>
<div class="form-table courses">
coursename and pupils...
</div>
<div class="form-table courses">
coursename and pupils...
</div>
```

My css is this:

```
.form-table.courses {page-break-after:always;}
```

Above will generate 4 pages because it sets page-break even after the third div above. **Is there any "simple" way of achieving to just get 3 pages?**

I was thinking of last-child property of css, but what I understand there are not support for this in IE8 and below - and that's not good enough (It must at least handle ie8 - preferebly ie7 as well).

Of course I could add a class for the last div and then modifiy the css like this:

```
<div class="form-table courses">
coursename and pupils...
</div>
<div class="form-table courses">
coursename and pupils...
</div>
<div class="form-table courses lastpage">
coursename and pupils...
</div>
```

and add this line to my css:

```
.form-table.courses.lastpage {page-break-after:"";}
```

Is my solution the only one to have some kind of cross-browser compability? Or am I missing some attribute/value of css that I should use instead?

Comment: How about [`page-break-before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before)? Or maybe [`.form-table.courses:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child).

Comment: page-break-before just adds a page in the beginning instead of the end. last-child is not supported in those browsers I would wish to :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`first-child` is supported down to IE7 so I would do the following:

```
.courses {
    page-break-before: always;
}

.courses:first-child {
    page-break-before: avoid;
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I thought of this when looking at Passerby's comment, but the avoid-attribute does not seem to be supported by Chrome, Firefox or Safari... ...so it still adds an empty page in the beginning.

Comment: Odd... Maybe try the method you mentioned in your post with `page-break-before: '';` Does that fix the problem? Or maybe try `inherit`?

Comment: No forgive me. I seemed to be totally wrong (avoid-attribute do work). It seems to be something with my divs that are not closed or something like that, because it worked on other pages :-) Thanks a LOT!!!

Answer (score 15):

Another way which is more readable is

```
.page-break {
    page-break-after: always;
}

.page-break:last-child {
    page-break-after: avoid;
}
```

This will break after all divs except the last one

```
<div id="container">
<div class="form-table page-break">
 <!-- First Child -->
 coursename and pupils...
</div>
<div class="form-table page-break">
 <!-- Second Child -->
 coursename and pupils...
</div>
<div class="form-table page-break">
 <!-- Third Child -->
 coursename and pupils...
</div>
<div class="form-table page-break">
 <!-- Last Child -->
 coursename and pupils...
</div>
</div>
```